# Deleting the numbering behind the Appendices in the TOC

Tags: appendices

I have a problem about Appendices.

I want to delete the numbering behind the Appendices in the TOC while I want the Appendices pages to appear by default in the first page of each Appendix. In other words, I ONLY want to delete the numbering.

I hope I be clear enough.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you only have *one* Appendix, and you want it to show in the TOC like "Appendix: Title ........ ##" where ## is the page number and *not* like "Appendix A: Title"?

Comment: No, I have 4 Appendices and want to appear in the TOC like
"Appendix A. Title1"

"Appendix B. Title2"

...

without any numbering at the behind of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of the appendix package that should help:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section{first}\section{second}
\begin{appendices}
\section{additional material}
\section{more of it}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

The `title` option puts "Appendix" in each appendix section heading, and `titletoc` puts "Appendix" in each ToC entry. More options are available, such as `page` to insert a page that says "Appendices". See the documentation for full details.

Comment: I knew there had to be a better way!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are not using `\appendix` before your appendices.

```
\section{Normal section}
\appendix
\section{First appendix}
\section{Second appendix}
```

Of course, that's going to show

```
1  Normal section
A  First appendix
B  Second appendix
```

and not `Appendix A`. The obvious fix of sticking `\renewcommand\thesection{\appendixname~\Alph{section}}` after `\appendix` does not work well with the table of contents. I'm sure there's a better way to do that.